# How to make an Android Spinner with initial text “Select One”?

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, android-spinner

**register.xml**

I want to use a Spinner that initially (when the user has not made a selection yet) displays the text "Select One". When the user clicks the spinner, the list of items is displayed and the user selects one of the options. After the user has made a selection, the selected item is displayed in the Spinner instead of "Select One".
I have the following code to create a Spinner:

```
<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/hospital"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/customeinput"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
```

**RegisterActivity.class**

```
//for selected item Listener


hospitalName();
        hospital_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String query = "select provider_sl from helthprovider_mst Where provider_name='" + hospital_name.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
                try {
                    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        provider_sl = rs.getInt("provider_sl");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



//for get data
    public void hospitalName() {
                String query = "select provider_name from helthprovider_mst where provider_type='1'";
                try {
                    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        //            database connection
        
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("provider_name");
                        data.add(name);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_selected_item, data);
                    NoCoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_drop_down);
                    hospital_name.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
        
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have to keep Select One as one of the options in the spinner items. And then have that item selected by default.

Comment: My data is retrieving from MSSQL database!

Comment: after retrieving, just add `Select One` at the index `0`

Comment: You mean I have to add "Select one" in my database?

Comment: No, I guess @GoutamSamal9 wants to say that when you retrieve the items from the database, then add "Select One" as one of the items in the list of items at the 0th position.

Comment: without adding in database how can I show "Select One" in spinner? is there any such solution?